# Media query on javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, media-queries, liquid-layout

I have the following snippet which I want to disable on tablets and mobiles.

```
if ( !! $('#sidebar').offset()) {    
        var stickyTop = $('#sidebar').offset().top;            
        $(window).scroll(function() {    
            var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();    
            if (stickyTop < windowTop) {
                $('#sidebar').css({ position: 'fixed', top: "120px" ,  right: "5%" });    
            }
            else {
                $('#sidebar').css('position', 'static');
            }

        });

    }
```

And I was thinking to wrap in inside a media query or something, like this:

```
if(@media (min-width:500px)){
if ( !! $('#sidebar').offset()) {

        var stickyTop = $('#sidebar').offset().top;


        $(window).scroll(function() {

            var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();

            if (stickyTop < windowTop) {
                $('#sidebar').css({ position: 'fixed', top: "120px" ,  right: "5%" });

            }
            else {
                $('#sidebar').css('position', 'static');
            }

        });

    }
}
```

But I'm sure that this wont work, so how would I stop this code from working on mobiles?

Comment: @ahren `var windowWidth = $(window).width(); if(windowsWidth > "800px"){functions here?}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution might be is to style some element differently (even if it's `margin:1px`) for each media and then detect the computed style. This way, you can use any CSS media rule equally easily and you get full compatibility:
CSS:

```
#widget{display:none}

@media screen{
  #widget{display:block}
}
```

JS:

```
if($("#widget").css("display")!="none){
   ...
}
```

Note that you should not query the media, but rather browser capabilities because the users of wide tablets (some even have keyboards) might still want to use your sidebar: `if(document.width>600){...`

Comment: I'm not styling anything differently for mobiles, as it's a liquid layout and everything looks perfect, but I'll try the if condition :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`matchMedia()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.matchMedia) like this:

```
if ( window.matchMedia('(min-width:500px)') ) {
  // your code
}
```

Be cautious, however, as this function is [not supported by all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia)!

**Edit**

A polyfill by Paul Irish can be found [here](https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/).

Comment: I could use it if the support would be greater, but as iOS 4.2.1 is not supporting it, and neither is android 2.3 and 2.2, this is not an option.

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen You could use a polyfill for those browsers like [the one by Paul Irish](https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/).

Comment: how about just `var windowWidth = $(window).width(); if(windowsWidth > "800px"){functions here?}`?

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen This might work in most cases, but I think, you'll run into problems with resized browser windows and alike.

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen `jQuery.width()` gets you the current width of the browser. So in case the user is resizing his browser, you might get false positive/negatives. So you will additionally have to put a handler to the `resize` event to account for that. You're not really getting the `min-width` of the user agent, but its current width!

Comment: But when it's used with `$(document).ready()`, it only runs once, right?

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen It runs just once, correct. So when the browser is set to very small dimensions at that point, you might mistake it for a mobile device.

Comment: It doesn't matter at that point, I'll just assume that user is browsing on normal dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( $(window).width() > 499 ) {
   // Code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Idk if this is the best way, but:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
body:after 
{
    content:url("javascript:(function(){document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML=' ';})()");
}
</style>
```

That is - using pseudoelements to add you particular javscript after `body` tag.

Another way is to assign different style to `body` tag or some special `hidden field` for different media and then detect this style from jQuery or ordinary javascript.

Checking **window width** is not the preferred method! The borders between ordinary screen devices and handhelds are gradually dimnishing.

Comment: I'd rather stay away from hacks.

Comment: Well, it's not that much a hack. You can just use some global variable, like 'deviceType' or something and then just assign this variable a value in the body:after preudoelement. All other .js code will just check this variable.

Comment: If that's not a hack, then there's no hacks.

Comment: Well, ok, you're right =) but then - setting different value to display css property and then checking is also a hack. I don't see ansers here that are 1) not a hack 2) do not simply check screen size

Answer (score 0):

Window width detection is a bit flaky at best: tablets are mobile devices more often than not feature big screens > 500px. I suggest you try [userAgent sniffing](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CC4QFjAB&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/best-way-to-detect-handheld-device-in-jquery&ei=kgqBUPD0EPS20QXjuoHgBA&usg=AFQjCNE4R_HqYS7XVYsSbz-rQuJBSqUQYg&cad=rja) , or the scripts at [detectmobilebrowsers.com/](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/). Another option is to use [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to check for touch-enabled devices

Answer (score 0):

You could use [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.matchMedia) as @Sirko very well pointed out and in order to have compatibility with older browsers you could use this [matchMedia polyfill](https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js) like so:

```
if (matchMedia('(min-width:500px)').matches) {
    // do your stuff
}
```